# How to match multiple lines in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

This doesn't matches multiple "m"

```
a = "Im the prowerful man"
puts a.match(/(m)/im)[1]
```

Above code matches only first "m"

In perl usually i do

```
$a =~ m/(m)/sig
```

How to do similarly in ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `string.scan` instead of `string.match` where the `match` function would return only the first match.

```
> a = "Im the prowerful man"
> a.scan(/m/im)
=> ["m", "m"]
> a.scan(/(m)/im)
=> [["m"], ["m"]]
```

Multidimensional array at the output is because of the capturing group present in your regex.